# Send multiple random radio button values to controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

I have built a cross platform app using Monaca, Onsen UI and AngularJS.

On a page I have a list of items, each with a sub-list of radio buttons created as below in my **view.html**

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="list__item" ng-repeat="checkItemDescription in data">
        <span class="list__item__line-height"><strong>{{checkItemDescription.checkitemdesc}}</strong></span>

        <label class="radio-button" ng-repeat="option in checkItemDescription.options">
            <input type="radio" 
                name="option_question_{{option.fleetcheckitemid}}" 
                ng-model="option.fleetcheckid">
            <div class="radio-button__checkmark"></div>
            {{option.checkvaluedesc}}
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The list is built and displayed as I want and the user can click on and of the radio buttons to select them.

When the user selects any of the radio buttons on any of the items, I need to save both the "*checkItemDescription*" ID as well as the "*option.fleetcheckid*" to a JSON object. My list of items can be of any length and I need to send each list item as a JSON object to my Database.

How do I send bot the "*checkItemDescription*" ID as well as the "*option.fleetcheckid*" when my ng-model only contains the value of "*option.fleetcheckid*"

Comment: One option is to use ng-click and pass both values to it like `ng-click=doSomething(checkItemDescription, fleetCheckId)`.  Inside of this method, you'd post the value to your database.  Or if you don't mind getting hacky, you could do a hidden input with ng-model.  `<input type="hidden" value="checkItemDescription" ng-model="option.checkItemDescription">`

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose is to be used one time, you can use **ng-hide** and pass the variable `$scope.InputSet` and then **ng-change**, on the function called set the `$scope.InputSet` as `true` and the logic you need.

```
<ul class="list" ng-hide="inputSet">
    <li class="list__item" ng-repeat="checkItemDescription in data">
        <span class="list__item__line-height"><strong>{{checkItemDescription.checkitemdesc}}</strong></span>

        <label class="radio-button" ng-repeat="option in checkItemDescription.options">
            <input type="radio" 
                name="option_question_{{option.fleetcheckitemid}}" 
                ng-model="option.fleetcheckid" 
                ng-change="funcToCall(checkItemDescription.id, option.fleetcheckitemid)">
            <div class="radio-button__checkmark"></div>
            {{option.checkvaluedesc}}
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Controller

```
$scope.funcToCall = function(checkItemDescription.id, option.fleetcheckitemid){
  $scope.inputSet = true;
  //Your logic...
};
```

If you want to remove just that checkbox you have to pass the option and delete it

```
$scope.funcToCall = function(checkItemDescription.id, option){
  // no need to use ng-hide here
  $scope.optionId = option.id;
    //remove the option
  delete option;
    //Your logic...
};
```

This should work.